# Space between subsections generated from doxygen

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, vertical-spacing, doxygen

I am using Doxygen to generate documentation for my C source code. Here is the sample of one of the latex files generated by Doxygen I am considering:

```
\doxysubsection{Function Documentation}
\mbox{\Hypertarget{gpio_8h_a04ac2ac79ab015b2d8d0fe82a498e183}\label{gpio_8h_a04ac2ac79ab015b2d8d0fe82a498e183}} 
\index{gpio.h@{gpio.h}!gpioDeInit@{gpioDeInit}}
\index{gpioDeInit@{gpioDeInit}!gpio.h@{gpio.h}}

\doxysubsubsection{\texorpdfstring{gpioDeInit()}{gpioDeInit()}}
{\footnotesize\ttfamily void gpio\+De\+Init (\begin{DoxyParamCaption}{ }\end{DoxyParamCaption})}

Desc\+: disables clock of all the G\+P\+IO ports.
```

The issue is with line space between doxysubsection "Function Documentation" and doxysubsubsection "gpioDeInit()". The spacing is huge which makes the document ugly. I have tried using \titlespacing in different forms as under:

```
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{2pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{1pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
%\titlespacing{\doxysection}{0pt}{*4}{*1.5}
%\titlespacing{\doxysubsection}{0pt}{*2}{*1.5}
%\titlespacing{\doxysubsubsection}{0pt}{*1}{*1.5}

%\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
%\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
%\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
```

None of the above seems to work.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Another issue is with the generation of index page, which seems to be an issue of doxygen. It generates multiple index entries for same entity. But that still can be ignored for now.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I don't know how `\doxysubsection` is defined, but I do know that there are "extra" spaces there that would produce unwanted *horizontal* space (the spaces between the `\index` entries resulting from the line breaks).  Regarding "duplicate" entries in the index, the index sort is dumb.  To be sorted together, entry texts have to be character-by-character identical; an extra space, for example, will cause a separate output entry.  Look for differences in the `.idx` file.

Comment: Also important to know which doxygen version you are using. The current `\doxysubsection` has as definition (with a newline after each `%` sign, the newline is unfortunately automatically removed from the comment): \newcommand\doxysubsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%` the definition of this can be found in `doxygen.sty` in the subdirectory templates/latex of doxygen (see also https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen).

Comment: Thank you for your response @barbarabeeton. Yes indexing is creating headache as of now. Actually I am a coder and this thing is taking me off from the real task at hand. I have decided to skip on generating index table as of now. Thank you for your response though

Comment: Thank you @albert for directing me to an important file. I have changed various numbers in that file to see if it reflect some change in the output pdf generated, but all in vain. I am sure I am doing some blunder there. Will come back to it once my project is ready and final doc is to be generated. 
I am using doxygen 1.8.19 to generate the documentation.

Thanks for your support